# Rail Fence (Zigzag) Cipher mathematical expression

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography

I'm working on Rail Fence Cipher encryption implementation. My current (valid) solution is:

```
public static string Encrypt(int height, string plainText)
{
    List<string> railFence = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) railFence.Add("");

    int pos = 0, inc = 1;
    foreach (char c in plainText)
    {
        if (pos + inc == height)
            inc = -1;
        else if (pos + inc == -1)
            inc = 1;

        railFence[pos] += c;
        pos += inc;
    }
    string encryptedtext = "";
    foreach (string s in railFence)
        encryptedtext += s;

    return encryptedtext;
}
```

But My problem is that I would like to create an expression which will calculate character position in plain text for given position in encrypted text (and also fence height and plain text length):

`positionPlainText = expr(positionInEncryptedText, N, plainText.Length)`

To make things a little bit more clear, this expression should answer this question:

"Hey expression! I would like to place character at position `X` in encrypted text, form which position `Y` in plain text should I take character and place there?"

I spent few hours with pen and paper and I'm still not able to create such and universal expression.